# Parsing xml tags with colons inside using C#

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

I'm working in Xamarin on one android app which is parsing xml from this webiste: http://video.cazin.net/rss.php, and populate listview and in particular I have a problem getting value from this tag:

```
 <media:thumbnail url="http://video.cazin.net/uploads/thumbs/2d07f1e49-1.jpg" width="480" height="360"/>
```

I created namespace:

```
xmlNameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("ab", "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");
```

and than tried to get value from url attribute:

```
XmlNodeList xmlNode = document.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item");
if (xmlNode[i].SelectSingleNode("//ab:thumbnail[@url='http://video.cazin.net/rss.php']", xmlNameSpaceManager) != null)
                {
                    var thumbnail = xmlNode[i].SelectSingleNode("//ab:thumbnail=[@url='http://video.cazin.net/rss.php']", xmlNameSpaceManager);
                    feedItem.Thumbnail = thumbnail.Value;
                }
```

I also tried something like this:

```
//ab:thumbnail/@url
```

but than I got value of just first image. I'm sure the problem is here somewhere because I have the same code parisng images from another xml tag without colon inside and it's working correctly. Does anyone had similar experience and knows what I should put in those braces? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query is searching for a `thumbnail` element where the `url` attribute is equal to `http://video.cazin.net/rss.php` - there are none that match this.

Your 'I also tried' query of `//ab:thumbnail/@url` is closer, but the `//` means that the query will start from the root of the document, so you get the all urls (but you only take the first).

If you want the element that matches taking the current node context into consideration, you need to include the current node context in the query - this is represented by `.`.  So `.//ab:thumbnail/@url` would find all `url` attributes in a `thumbnail` element contained by the current node. You can see the result in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MVYU3o).

I would strongly suggest you use LINQ to XML instead, however.  It's a lot nicer to work with than the old `XmlDocument` API.  For example, you could find all item thumbnail urls using this code:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("http://video.cazin.net/rss.php");

XNamespace media = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";

var thumbnailUrls = doc.Descendants("item")
    .Descendants(media + "thumbnail")
    .Attributes("url");
```

Comment: When something doesn't work just because of tiny little dot. Thank you so much sir. Next time I will use LINQ to XML.